# Visual basic error "Could not find file"

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to open a database in Visual BASIC.net. This is my code so far,

```
Private Sub btnLoad_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnLoad.Click
    Dim con As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
    Dim dbProvider As String
    Dim dbSource As String

    dbProvider = "PROVIDER=Microsoft.jet.OLEDB.4.0;"
    dbSource = "Data Source = C:\Documents and Settings\somar\Desktop\Dropbox\Visual Studio 2010 VB.net\Projects\AddressBook.mbd"

    con.ConnectionString = dbProvider & dbSource

    con.Open()
    MsgBox("Database is now open")

    con.Close()
    MsgBox("Database is not closed")

End Sub
```

The error occurs I try click the button. VB says that it is not able to fin the path to the file. I've changed the location to the Desktop but that didn't change much. I'm not sure why this occurs, nay help you be greatly appreciated.

I'm fairly new to programming.

Thanks

Comment: Just a suggestion
use TRY...CATCH block while opening or closing the DB connection. So if any error/exception occurs, you will get a notification.
Example:
Try
   con.Open()
    MsgBox("Database is now open")
Catch(Exception ex)
    con.Close()
    MsgBox("Database is not closed")
End Try

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably change `mbd` to `mdb` in your filename.

You should also use `OleDbConnectionStringBuilder` instead of string concatenation, and should should use a `Using` block instead of explicitly calling `Close()`.

Comment: Thanks! That was the problem.